# Redirect to '/' on page reload react-router-dom v5

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

How do I get react-router-dom to go to the root page of my app when I reload?

There are some posts saying to use the `exact` keyword but that isn't working.

Example:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";

const Component = () => {

    return (
      <div id="app">
         <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={ExampleComponent} />
            <Route path="/example_route_1" component={ExampleComponent1} />
            <Route path="/example_route_2" component={ExampleComponent2} />
            <Route path="/example_route_3" component={ExampleComponent3} />
            <Route path='*'>404</Route>
         </Switch>
      </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To route back to `/` on reload, simply push to history with `useEffect()`, make sure to add the empty array at the end so it only runs once.

This will push the root path (or whatever route you push in `useEffect()`) regardless of where the user was located prior reload.

Example:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const Component = () => {

    const history = useHistory();
        
    useEffect(() => {
      history.push("/");
    }, []);

    return (
      <div id="app">
         <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={ExampleComponent} />
            <Route path="/example_route_1" component={ExampleComponent1} />
            <Route path="/example_route_2" component={ExampleComponent2} />
            <Route path="/example_route_3" component={ExampleComponent3} />
            <Route path='*'>404</Route>
         </Switch>
      </div>
    )
}
```